# Simulator not running XCTest tests

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, xcode5.1

I am new to running unit tests in Xcode (with XCText). I created an empty iOS application and just tried running the tests (which should fail by default). The iOS simulator starts and the toolbar console just shows "testing..." and it just hangs forever. I don't see any error in the console. If I try running the tests on a device (iPhone 5 in my case), the tests run just fine.

I am using Xcode 5.1.1 and simulator 7.1

Any idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: Try stuff like restarting your computer. Xcode often has trouble synchronizing itself with the simulator even when I'm just _running_ the app, let alone testing.

Comment: Oh, and don't get me started about how long it takes just to _launch_ the simulator! I could write a whole new app in the time it takes...

Comment: still not working after restart. I also tried cleaning the project. The simulator is really frustrating.